# How to calculate Logits the same way it is done in PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

Regarding Logits, this is my understanting:

> What is a Logit? A Logit function, also known as the log-odds
> function, is a function that represents probability values from 0 to
> 1, and negative infinity to infinity.

source: https://deepai.org/machine-learning-glossary-and-terms/logit

I would like to understand how logits are calculated in PyTorch from this PDF (probabity density function). I don’t know how to reproduce it.

```
probs = torch.tensor([ 0.1,  0.2, 0.5,  0.2])
categorical_distribution = Categorical(probs=probs)
categorical_distribution.logits
```

the output is:

```
tensor([-2.3026, -1.6094, -0.6931, -1.6094])
```

I am using this definition of logit to achieve the same result:

[image: Definition of Logit]

The results I am getting using the formula and the values mentioned above are:

```
print(np.log(0.1 /(1 - 0.1)), np.log(0.2 /(1 - 0.2)), np.log(0.5 /(1 - 0.5)), np.log(0.2 /(1 - 0.2)))

-2.19722457734 -1.38629436112 0.0 -1.38629436112
```

Comment: did you confirm if the random seed is same?

Answer (score 1):

A call to [`Categorical.logits`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/distributions/categorical.html#Categorical) internally makes use of a function called
[`probs_to_logits`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/b2b0a0d3baf6258fbf728572719937810fd890ce/torch/distributions/utils.py#L84). Going through the linked code, you can see that torch does not use your definition of a logit; it considers logits to simply be log probabilities.

You can confirm this in numpy as well:

```
>>> np.log([ 0.1,  0.2, 0.5,  0.2])
array([-2.30258509, -1.60943791, -0.69314718, -1.60943791])
```